# results between two 9am and 10pm - mysql

Tags: mysql, time

I would like run a mysql to find all results between 9am to 10am.

I want it to find all results no matter what day it is. I can find the results for a certain day but not for all results

Answer (score 3):

Having a `DateTime` object as column, just use inbuilt functions to extract the hour:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE HOUR(t.DateTimeColumn) >= 9 AND HOUR(t.DateTimeColumn) <= 22
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE HOUR(t.DateTimeColumn) BETWEEN 9 AND 22
```

See:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using the hour() function.

It would be something like this:

```
select *
from table
where hour(timestamp_col) >= 9
and hour(timestamp_col) <= 10;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour

Comment: Psst... that will return no results. There are no hours that are greater than 9 and less than 10 :-)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the filter `where hour(yourtimestampcolumn) between 9 and 10`

or `between 9 and 22` for 10PM

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE TIME(datetime column) BETWEEN '09:00' AND '10:00';
```

Answer (score -1):

This will also help you if date is stored like this :- '2013-09-18 11:47:12'

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE substr(created,12,8) > '09:00:00' and substr(created,12,8) < '10:00:00'
```